# Sampling ends of "Curve to Mesh" generated mesh or between?

Tags: geometry-nodes

After generating a mesh from curve and profile curve,
what would be the recommended method to sample edge loop from the beginning and end of the mesh?

Could I approach this by using the curve and sampling the nearest edges to curve point?

Comment: As some alternatives to quellenform's solution: Edge neighbors -> Equal: 1 when you have no caps, when you have caps that aren't quads, you can select the tri/n-gon faces, and yet another alternative, you can simply select $n$ first and last points, where $n$ is the number of points in the "profile curve".

Answer (score 4):

To select the ends of a mesh that you have created with `Curve to Mesh`, simply capture the end points in the base curve beforehand with `Capture Attributes`.

Something like this:

[image]